# Accessing the container in Symfony2 WebTestCase, returns NULL

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to access the container in a Symfony2 WebTestCase and i'm getting NULL. Any ideas? Here's my code:

```
$this->client = static::createClient();
$container = $this->client->getContainer();
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming that you extend from `WebTestCase` class, you should call `$this->createClient()` instead of static method.

In case if you call this method as static, you should execute `boot()` method

```
    static::$kernel = static::createKernel($options);
    static::$kernel->boot();

    $client = static::$kernel->getContainer()->get('test.client');
    $client->setServerParameters($server);
```

**Be sure** to create client inside `setUp()`

Comment: Still getting NULL. This is very strange.

Comment: @vinnylinux We should probably start a chat :)

Comment: I forgot to boot()